# Can sequence over infinite maybes ever terminate?

Tags: haskell, fold, strictness

In other words, can the following be optimized to `Just [1..]`?

```
> sequence (map Just [1..])
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

There is also a more specific example in `data61/fp-course` where early termination is expected iff an `Empty` value is present.

```
seqOptional ::
  List (Optional a)
  -> Optional (List a)
seqOptional =
    foldRight f (Full Nil)
      where
          f Empty _ = Empty
          f _ Empty = Empty
          f (Full a) (Full as) = Full (a :. as)
```

Why does changing order of the first two patterns make function loop forever as if `Empty` cannot be ever matched? I vaguely understand that such definition would make `f` strict in the infinite list, but I don't see what is actually causing this.

Or are these unrelated problems?

Side question: does it matter that stack is exhausted and not heap?

Comment: `map Just [1..]` is not equivalent to `Just [1..]`. The result is `[Just 1, Just 2, ...]`.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if `sequence` can construct the theoretical answer `Just [1..]` without having to examine the infinitely many elements of its input.

Comment: I feel like there are two separate questions here. Perhaps consider asking the `seqOptional` part as a separate question, with an MCVE of the behavior you describe. I can't exactly see how changing the order of the first two patterns would change anything, so if you have a specific call that does so, please post it.

Comment: "Why does changing order of the first two patterns make function loop forever" - I can't reproduce this behaviour. Please include a MCVE. You can't optimize `sequence (map Just [1..])` to `Just [1..]` because the former is bottom while the latter is not (these two terms do not denote the same value - the first doesn't even have a value). Maybe your question is, can one define a function `s` such that `s = sequence` for finite lists and `s (map Just [1..]) = Just [1..]` - the answer is still no, because `s` would have to examine infinitely many elements, and then terminate (which is nonsense).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if it could, it shouldn't.  As in @user2407038's comment, according to Haskell's [denotational semantics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics), `sequence (map Just [1..])`  denotes a different value than `Just [1..]`.

Haskell functions are *continuous*, which is the key tool for reasoning precisely about infinite data structures.  To illustrate what continuity means, suppose we have an infinite sequence of values which are increasingly defined, for example:

```
⟂
1:⟂
1:2:⟂
1:2:3:⟂
```

Now, apply a function to each of them, let's say `tail`:

```
tail ⟂             = ⟂
tail (1:⟂)         = ⟂
tail (1:2:⟂)       = 2:⟂
tail (1:2:3:⟂)     = 2:3:⟂
     ⋮                 ⋮
tail [1..]         = [2..]
```

What it means for a function to be continuous is that if you apply the function to the *limit* of the sequence of arguments, you get the *limit* of the sequence of results, as illustrated in the final line.

Now some observations about `sequence` on partially defined lists:

```
-- a ⟂ after a bunch of Justs makes the result ⟂
sequence (Just 1 : Just 2 : ⟂) = ⟂
-- a Nothing anywhere before the ⟂ ignores the ⟂ (early termination)
sequence (Just 1 : Nothing : ⟂) = Nothing
```

We only need the first observation.  We can now ask your question:

```
sequence (map Just ⟂)       = sequence ⟂                     = ⟂
sequence (map Just (1:⟂))   = sequence (Just 1 : ⟂)          = ⟂
sequence (map Just (1:2:⟂)) = sequence (Just 1 : Just 2 : ⟂) = ⟂
          ⋮                                   ⋮                 ⋮
sequence (map Just [1..])                                    = ⟂
```

So by continuity, `sequence (map Just [1..]) = ⟂`.  If you "optimized" it to give a different answer, that optimization would be incorrect.

Comment: So, should I understand that in Haskell semantics, multiplying infinite amount of `1`s is bottom and not `1`? Where can I read more about this?

Comment: @sevo The [wikibook page on denotational semantics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics) is where I got started.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer your second question, but can answer your first one.

In theory the compiler can detect and optimize cases like this, but due to the Halting Problem it's impossible for it to detect *every* instance of this pattern. The best it can do is a bunch of ad-hoc heuristics, and I think it would be more confusing if the termination of your program depended on whether a particular rewrite rule fired or not.